# Can't get global variables in twig to work

Tags: symfony, twig

So I have Twig running on top of Symfony 2.7. In the output html I'd like to have a few modules of text and in the last module I want some summary from all the previous ones (some data from all the previous modules' Entities) and I figured I'd append these summaries to a global variable while generating modules themselves to avoid a second loop. The code I'm using:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% set list = '' %} {# HERE I SET A GLOBAL VAR #}
{% block body %}

    <section>
        <h2>{% trans %}MODULES{% endtrans %}</h2>
        {% for m in plan.Modules %}
        {{- block('module') -}}
        {{ list }} {# HERE JUST FOR TESTING - IT'S EMPTY #}
        {% endfor %}


    </section>
    {{ list }} {# HERE I WANT IT DISPLAYED, YET IT'S EMPTY :( #}

{% endblock %}
{% block module %}

    <h3>{{ m.Module.title }}</h3>
    {# HERE SOME MODULE TEXT I GET FROM COMPLICATED RELATIONS #}

{% if m.Module.list %}
{% set temp %}
{{ m.Module.shortTitle }}<br/>
{% endset %}

{% set list = list~temp %}

{% for l in m.Module.list %}
{% set temp %}
  {{ l }}
  {% endset %}
  {% set list = list~temp %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% endif %}
{{ list }} {# HERE IT'S WORKING #}
{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should move the code that concatenate the string above the code where you try to output the string... Code is run from top-down, so you can't expect `list` to be non-empty if you it set it below the output of it

Comment: It's inside a block that gets executed before printing `list`. Even so, if I move the block 'module' before block 'body' the effect is exactly the same.